# Trying to get Facebook Photos of my friends

Tags: c++, facebook, sdk, cocos2d-iphone, photo

Since some weeks, i'm having problems for GET facebook photos of "my friends". I've more than one friend, and when i try to get all photos, i can get only one. When i request the second photo of my second friend, i receive this response "**The request timed out.**". It worked until a few months ago. Since weeks, it doesn't work anymore.

I'm sure that the problem isn't in my code, because the URL that i'm using for the request, works ok. In fact, as i said before, i didn't change anything in my code, and it worked until a few months ago...

It sounds like a limitation in the API. Anyone can help me?

```
for(....) //my friend list
{
  HttpRequest* requestFacebookPhoto = new HttpRequest();
  requestFacebookPhoto->setUrl(friendPhotoUrl); //I tested all URLs in Chrome and it works. The url is ok.
  requestFacebookPhoto->setRequestType(HttpRequest::Type::GET);
  requestFacebookPhoto->setResponseCallback([](HttpClient* client, HttpResponse* response) {

    if (!response or response->getResponseCode() != 200) {

        //response code is -1, so, when i debug it, it enters to this if

        return;
    }

    //more code below..

  }); 

  HttpClient::getInstance()->send(requestFacebookPhoto);
  requestFacebookPhoto->release();
}
```

I expect to get all photos of my friends, like before, in the past. I repeat, i didn't change anything. It worked in production ok, with the same code. I'm developing in C++ using cocos2d http library.

Maybe the "time out" is because i'm requesting a lot of photos in few time? I've only five or six friends.. so i'm requesting five or six photos in a 'short' time, inside the 'for'. But it worked before...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get photos of friends, you can only get photos of the currently authorized user. It may have worked several years ago, but Facebook removed access to friend data with v2.0 of the Graph API, for privacy reasons.

Scraping is not allowed, so if there is no way with the Graph API, don´t do it. The photos/data of other users (no matter if friends or not) are none of your business, if they did not specifically authorize your App to access them.

For authorized users, just use /user-id/photos with a user token. And if that does not work with your user token, you may have to store/cache the photos when the friend enters the app, with his own token.

Comment: I'm trying to get photos of my friends that plays the game too. In other words, as you said, photos of the currently authorized users. So, that's not the problem. I should get the photos that i'm requesting. Help me plz....

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the URL that i'm requesting for get a photo of my friend, works ok! If I enter to that URL in Chrome or IE or Firefox i can download their photo. However, when i try to get it by code, i receive the response "The request timed out.". Why? What changes did Facebook team recently? Because this worked for me in the past, with the same code!

Comment: Anyone can help me?